# Incorrect used space in Quotas Manager

Tags: windows-server-2008

We are facing a strange issue,
The quota manager (in Server manager) shows wrong used space, while TreeSize shows other results.

TreeSize: 269.4MB
Folder properties: 266 MB
Quota manager:     805 MB

What can be the reason?

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you check if the Recycle Bin is empty?

Comment: Sure, besides, the Recycle Bin isn't under C:\users, but under C:\$recycle.bin

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/bdcdf491-c982-44b4-bb25-5ba468eb7aca/fsrm-and-quotas-showing-incorrect-values?forum=winserverfiles#a6e0af69-6b03-42f3-902b-48b16bcd8aaa) it seems that the server's disk usage tracking can get off under some circumstances.

In that case you need to rescan the affected folders using the *dirquota* command:

```
dirquota quota scan /path:<Path> [/remote:<ComputerName>]
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742101.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue, End user profile folder show 99% used, but in side that folder is only 13 MB used for 50 MB quota.

Solution: I removed the quota and added it back again. Then the issue resolved.